# Concatenating XML files with shell not working as expected

Tags: xml, bash, shell, data-manipulation

I have been trying to modify a script concatenating xml files from a path and merge them into a single xml, this script was originally used for concatenating text files.

I have the following script

```
#!usr/bin/sh
ORIGIN_PATH="/backup/data/export/imatchISO"
HISTORY_PATH="/backup/data/batch/hist"
SEND_PATH="/backup/data/batch/output"
DATE=`date +%y%m%d`
LOG="/backup/data/batch/log/concatIMatch_"$DATE

cd $ORIGIN_PATH

ls -lrt >> $LOG

cat $ORIGIN_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053_* >> $SEND_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053.XML_$DATE 2>> $LOG

mv $ORIGIN_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053_* $HISTORY_PATH >> $LOG 2>> $LOG


if [[ $(ls -A $SEND_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053.XML_$DATE) ]]; then
    echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Ficheros 053 concatenados"  >> $LOG
        mv $SEND_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053.XML_$DATE $SEND_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053.XML 2>> $LOG
        exit 0
else
    echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Â¡ERROR CON LOS FICHEROS 053 AL CONCATENAR!"  >> $LOG
        exit 1
fi
```

and what I have is a path containing several xml files with the same format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

</DataPDU>
```

the thing is that when I concatenate with this is appending the end of the file to the next one , which is not the expected result as it is duplicating the xml declaration tag and the opening `<DataPDU>` and closing `<DataPDU>` for all files.

What I'm needing is to have a single xml file with the following sctructure

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

</DataPDU>
```

So technically what I want is to have the first 3 lines and the last line only occurring once.

I have received a tip that I could do something with:

```
$ awk 'NR<3 {print} FNR>3 {print last} {last=$0} END{print}' *.xml
```

But I don't understand how to modify my script for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `xmllint` to properly process XML files and excluding `Revision` Element from second body

```
body1=$(xmllint --xpath '/DataPDU/*' tmp.xml | sed -ze 's/\n/\&#xA;/g')
body2=$(xmllint --xpath '/DataPDU/*[not(local-name()="Revision")]' tmp.xml | sed -ze 's/\n/\&#xA;/g')

printf "%s\n" "cd /DataPDU" "set ${body1}${body2}" "save" "bye" | xmllint --shell tmp.xml
```

Code uses same file twice so change second file name accordingly.
Plain new lines `\n` are replaced by its equivalent `&#xA;` entity to avoid errors on `xmllint` shell.

`awk` can be used too but requires that XML format does not change between files.
Body can be extracted by setting record separator RS to
`xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">` or `</DataPDU>`
Record #2 contains the inner elements.

```
# from any file
echo -e '<?xml version="1.0" ?>\n\t<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">' > output.xml

# concatenate bodies on a variable from all files
for f in *.xml; do
    body+=$(gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="xmlns:ns2=\"urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0\">|<[/]DataPDU>" } { if(NR == 2) { print $0 }}' "$f")
 done
 
echo "$body" >> output.xml
# Add closing tag
echo "</DataPDU>" >> output.xml
```

Comment: this kinda starts to work, but it loses the xml tag entirely and the DataPDU ones, the resulting file starts with `<ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>` and finished with `</ns2:Body>`

Comment: @Baldie47 Added how to use it.

Comment: I've changed to this:
`#!/bin/bash

# concatenate bodies on a variable
body+=$(gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="xmlns:ns2=\"urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0\">|<[/]DataPDU>" } { if(NR == 2) { print $0 }}' *.xml)
# on last file
gawk -v body="$body" 'BEGIN{ RS="xmlns:ns2=\"urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0\">|<[/]DataPDU>" } { if(NR == 2) { print $0 body }else{print $0}}' *.xml > output.xml`

but the resulting file is not in format

Comment: the resulting file is 3 repetitions (I have 3 xml for test)  that start with:
`<?xml version="1.0" ?><DataPDU 
<ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision><ns2:`

Comment: and don't have the closing DataPDU tag

Comment: First, get bodies for all but last file, then apply on last file. After that, `echo "</DataPDU>" >> output.xml`

Comment: what's the `for f in file1 file2 file 3`?  is the same if I do `for f in *.xml` ?

Comment: and I guess in the first line I can replace `test_1.xml` with `*.xml`?

Comment: No, first line uses a single file, any of them. Changed for loop to use *.xml

Comment: ohh, shoudl I have in this case a template? because all the files have dynamic names, son I can't hardcode one

Comment: I also get some `gawk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{ RS="xmlns:ns2=\"urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0\">|<[/]DataPDU>" } { if(NR == 1) { print $0 "xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0"> }
gawk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                             ^ syntax error  (with the arrow pointing to : in `run:swift`

Comment: In that case just replace the first line with `echo -e '<?xml version="1.0" ?>\n\t<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">' > output.xml`

Comment: that seems to have worked!

Comment: Thank you very much @LMC, it looks like this version is doing what it needs, I'm running more tests now, but looks good!